# What is the difference between using python Pillow's ImageOps mirror and flip options, and doing an affine transformation?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, affinetransform

I'm trying to reflect and compare some images, for example, if I reflect image A, is it equivalent to image B.  As of now I am using Pillow's mirror and flip options to make the comparison.  I am reading about affine transformations as another way to rotate/mirror/flip images, but I can't find much information on the differences between using the library options and personally doing an affine transformation on an image. How does pillow's libraries reflect/flip/rotate images, and what is its difference in outcomes compared to an affine transformation?  Thanks!

Comment: I would imagine that mirror and flip simply shuffle the existing data about in memory very fast and are only capable of multiples of 90 degrees, whereas affine transformations likely do lots of maths (sines & cosines) and are able to transform more flexibly through any desired angles. You can always read the source.

Comment: affine transformation is just lots of multiplication and addition. coming up with the matrix takes _one-time_ calculations for the coefficients. -- please show that you've researched your question. show what you've learned. it should be more than what you've shown so far.